Why do I not get the more helpful "sum() can't sum strings, use join" message, but "unsupported operand types for +"?
I'm learning Python now.
I created a function
def my_func(my_tuple):
    return sum(my_tuple)

Then I do
print(my_func(("a", "b")))

And I get:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

But when I call sum directly, I get this:
    print(sum("a", "b"))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]

I understand that I can't use sum with strings, and how to fix it, but why do I get two different messages?

Per the documentation of sum:

sum(iterable, /, start=0)
Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

sum is meant to add numbers, with a default start value of 0, so sum(("a", "b")) is equivalent to:
0 + "a" + "b"

And since Python doesn't support adding an integer with a string, you get the said TypeError.
In theory you should be able to work around the issue by specifying an empty string "" as a start value with sum(("a", "b"), start="") so it becomes equivalent to "" + "a" + "b". But for efficiency reasons specifying a string as a start value has been explicitly disallowed in favor of calling ''.join(("a", "b")), since  ''.join would pre-allocate memory for all the strings being joined instead of creating a new string object for each join operation, which is why calling sum(("a", "b"), start="") would produce:
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]


You only get the nicer second message if you pass a string as start parameter of the builtin sum(iterable, start=0) function.
There is a difference between calling sum(("a", "b")) and sum("a", "b"):
By sum(("a", "b")), you are passing one argument, ("a", "b"), which gets assigned to the iterable parameter of the sum function, and start will be the default value 0.
By sum("a", "b"), you are passing two arguments, "a" and "b", where iterable is "a" and start is "b".

The my_func function forwards the tuple ("a", "b") as-is to sum. If you had wanted my_func(("a", "b")) to have the same effect as sum("a", "b"), you would have to unpack the tuple:
def my_func(my_tuple):
    return sum(*my_tuple)

(However this would be wrong for the purpose of actually getting the sum of the values in my_tuple, and your original function was correct.)
Conversely, if you wanted my_func("a", "b") to have the same effect as sum(("a", "b")) then you would have to write
def my_func(*values):
    return sum(values)

This would be a valid use case.
